# how to find string in php?

Tags: php

```
<form name="search" method="post" >
Input texts and numbers: <input type="text" name="find"><br>
</form>
<?php
 if(!empty($_POST)){
   echo $_POST['find'];    
 }
```

Question:

I want to `echo all the contents before texts` (including texts), eg. if user input `'mynumber11`', then it shows `'mynumber'`, if user input `'123mynumber11'`, then it shows `'123mynumber'`, how to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify you want to strip the last 11. If the last 2 digits are 11, you want those to be stripped out?

Comment: i want to strip all the digits after text, if the input is '232mytext3455', then it shows '232mytext'

Comment: @chandresh_cool As was noted, there is no need to post comments to notify someone of your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just strip off all digits before end:

```
if(!empty($_POST))
    $findStr = preg_replace('/\d+$/', '', $_POST['find']);
```

Comment: i want to keep the digits before texts.

Comment: Yes above will do that, its only removing digits just for end of text.

Comment: **[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/zC1PGwxKt7)**

Comment: imo, regular expressions are overkill for these simple matters.

Comment: @Jack; Thanks so much for fixing the syntax issue in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim):

```
echo rtrim($_POST['find'], '1234567890');
```

Comment: rtrim removes whitespaces and character specified at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$str = "123mynumber11";

do
{
    $n = substr($str,-1);
    if(is_numeric($n))
        $str = substr($str,0,-1);
}
while(is_numeric($n));

echo($str);
```